# Linq Join query returning empty dataset

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using below code to join two tables based on `officeId` field. Its retuning 0 records.

> ```
>   IQueryable<Usage> usages = this.context.Usage;
>   usages = usages.Where(usage => usage.OfficeId == officeId);
>
>   var  agencyList = this.context.Agencies.ToList();
>   var usage = usages.ToList();
>   var query =  usage.Join(agencyList,
>                                      r => r.OfficeId,
>                                      a => a.OfficeId,
>                                      (r, a) => new UsageAgencyApiModel () { 
>                                             Id = r.Id,
>                                             Product = r.Product,
>                                             Chain = a.Chain,
>                                             Name = a.Name
>                                      }).ToList();
> ```

I have 1000+ records in agencies table and 26 records in usage table.

I am expecting 26 records as a result with **chain** and **name** colums attached to result from agency table.

Its not returning anything. I am new to .net please guide me if I am missing anything

> EDIT

@Tim Schmelter's solution works fine if I get both table context while executing join. But I need to add filter on top of usage table before applying join

```
 IQueryable<Usage> usages = this.context.Usage;

usages = usages.Where(usage => usage.OfficeId == officeId);

 
            var query = from a in usages 
           // works with this.context.usages instead of usages
            join u in this.context.Agencies on a.OfficeId equals u.OfficeId
            select new  
            { 
               Id = a.Id,
               Product = a.Product,
               Chain = u.Chain,
               Name = u.Name
            };
return query.ToList();
```

Attaching screenshot here

[image]

same join query works fine with in memory data as you see below

[image]

Both ways works fine if I add in memory datasource or both datasource directly. But not working if I add filter on `usages` based on `officeId` before applying join query

Comment: If `context` is eg an EF database context, and your navigation is set up correctly you don't need to do this... You just do `context.Usage.Select(r => new UsageAgencyApiModel () { Id = r.Id, Product = r.Product, Chain = r.Agency.Chain, Name = r.Agency.Name})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem ist that you load all into memory first(`ToList()`).

With joins i prefer query syntax, it is less verbose:

```
var query = from a in this.context.Agencies
            join u in this.context.Usage on a.OfficeId equals u.OfficeId
            select new UsageAgencyApiModel() 
            { 
               Id = u.Id,
               Product = u.Product,
               Chain = a.Chain,
               Name = a.Name
            };

List<UsageAgencyApiModel> resultList = query.ToList();
```

Edit: You should be able to apply the `Where` after the `Join`. If you still don't get records there are no matching:

```
var query = from a in this.context.Agencies
            join u in this.context.Usage on a.OfficeId equals u.OfficeId
            where u.OfficeId == officeId
            select new UsageAgencyApiModel{ ... };
```

Comment: This works fine if I get both table context while executing join. But I need to add filter on top of usage table before join like below. Please check edit part of the question. I have updated my question with your solution

Comment: @IamGrooot: You forgot to mention the problem, what is not working, you get an exception?

Comment: It returns empty data set like my original code. Both way works fine if I add in memory datasource  or both  datasource directly from db context as you mentioned.  But not working if I add filter on `usages` before applying join

Comment: @IamGrooot: I showed you now how to apply the filter after the join. But i would expect that your query also works. Anyway, have a look.

Comment: My Bad. Office Id which I was entering was not present in agency table hence the issue. Its working for other offices. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code can help to get the output based on the ID value.

Of course, I wrote with Lambda.

```
var officeId = 1;
var query = context.Agencies    // your starting point - table in the "from" statement
   .Join(database.context.Usage, // the source table of the inner join
      agency => agency.OfficeId,        // Select the primary key (the first part of the "on" clause in an sql "join" statement)
      usage  => usage.OfficeId ,   // Select the foreign key (the second part of the "on" clause)
      (agency,  usage) => new {Agency = agency, Usage = usage }) // selection
   .Where(x => x.Agency.OfficeId == id);    // where statement
```